# Geocoding api is giving wrong decimal values

Tags: excel, geocoding

I am trying to calculate distances between GPS waypoints in Excel using Google's geocoding api

The geocoding API translates these Waypoint to decimals

```
WP1: S25 07 25.9 W57 20 22.1 = -25.1238745,-57.3396070 
WP2: S25 07 02.4 W57 19 15.1 = -25.1162286,-57.3175897
```

Using these coordinates in the distance API results in a total of 2,374 metres.

Using http://transition.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html to translate:

```
WP1: S25 07 25.9 W57 20 22.1 = -25.123861, 57.339472
WP2: S25 07 02.4 W57 19 15.1 = -25.117333, 57.320861
```

Using these coordinates in the distance API results in a total of 2,010 metres

Can anyone explain why the Geocoding API is giving wrong values?

Comment: either you use the api the wrong way, or it is a big piece of shit. 25 + 7/60 + 25.9/3600 is exatly thge value that the website provides.

Comment: As a slight aside, *how* are you doing it in Excel using Google's API?

Comment: @ChrisW, the how is easy. He's using the functions from my site (Google for G_DISTANCE and G_LATLNG and you'll turn it up). For why it's not working, it looks to me like the Directions API rounds off the precision to 5 places (it returns to 7 places but the last two are always zeros) while the Google Maps website doesn't. I suggested the OP post here in the hope that someone would have an idea about workarounds.

Comment: @JamieBull - found it - I'd never seen a web API with a VBA wrapper (although of course there's no reason why not); yes - I'd initially assume it would be to do with rounding too, but the values he's got seem strange...

Comment: The lat/lng pairs all lie on the road. I'm thinking there must be two different algorithms for finding the right spot on the road to use depending on the precision of the lat/lng.

Comment: if you use the right coordinates, the G_DISTANCE finds the correct meters... Now I'm skipping the G_LATLNG API converting the waypoints to decimals in Excel...

Comment: Jamie, I don't think is a round problem...

how -25.123861 ends up in -25.1238745 

:D

Comment: In your first set of coordinates, how are you storing lat/lon?  as floats?  You should store decimal lat/lon's as doubles.

Comment: TreyA, I'm using mapsource to manage the GPS Waypoints. Then, I save them in a txt format which I use to feed the Jamie Excel G_LATLGN function.

Comment: My spidey sense was tingling when I saw that only 5 decimal places were seen with lat/lon.  With a IEEE 32-bit float, you get 7 significant figures.  Two are used for the degree (in your lat/lon case) which leaves 5 decimal places.  Have you tried a lon with triple digit degrees (W123 45 67.8) to see if you only get 4 decimal places?  If so, it appears lat/lon is being stored as a float somewhere.